# How to switch between properties file depending on selected profile

Tags: java, spring

We have profiles described as :

```
<profiles>
     <!-- Local/Windows development  -->
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation/>
        <properties>
            <INSTALL_MACHINE_LIST>localhost</INSTALL_MACHINE_LIST>
            <COPY_MODE>local</COPY_MODE>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- Development -->
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation/>
        <properties>
            <INSTALL_MACHINE_LIST>dev01</INSTALL_MACHINE_LIST>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- QA -->
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <activation/>
        <properties>
            <INSTALL_MACHINE_LIST>dqa01</INSTALL_MACHINE_LIST>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- Production -->
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation/>
        <properties>
            <INSTALL_MACHINE_LIST>prod01</INSTALL_MACHINE_LIST>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

For our test environment, we have 2 properties file **(under src/main/test/resources**) **application-local.properties** and **application.properties** file. The plan is to use application-local.properties in "local" profile mode ( on our development windows system) and application.properties for rest of the profile modes. In spring context (spring-context.xml),  currently, we are manually switching between 2 properties file depending on what profile we are using. Looking for a way  to select automatically application-local.properties for "local" profile and application.properties for any other type of  profile. Is there a way to use if-then-else condition in xml based spring-context file?  **I tried** :

```
<bean id="flag" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <constructor-arg value="#{ profile == 'local' ? true: false }" />
</bean>
<util:properties id="machineMetaDbProps" location="#{ flag ? 'application-local.properties' : 'application.properties' }"/>
```

**Getting error :**

```
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'profile' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?'
```

Comment: Are you talking about Maven profiles or Spring profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Xml Config:

In XML based config, you can make properties files related to a profile accessible to Spring via:

```
<beans profile="local">
    <context:property-placeholder 
             location="classpath:docker-db.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
</beans>
<beans profile="test">    
      <context:property-placeholder
             location="classpath:test-db.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
</beans>
```

---

## Java Config:

Regarding to the active profile, you can also manually feed properties file to the spring vi java config as:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public class LocalPropertyReader {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] {
            new ClassPathResource("docker-db.properties"), new ClassPathResource("application-local.properties")
        };
        ppc.setLocations(resources);
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }
}



@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class ProdPropertyReader {


    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] {
            new ClassPathResource("test-db.properties"), new ClassPathResource("application-test.properties")
        };
        ppc.setLocations(resources);
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }
}
```

---

## Enabling Profile:

> This can be done in following ways:
>
> - Using Spring context environment : `ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("local");`
> - Using system property : `System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "local");`
> - Passing a system parameter at run time: `-Dspring.profiles.active="local"`
> - Enabling profile in web.xml
>
>   ```
>   <context-param>
>       <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
>       <param-value>local</param-value>
>   </context-param>
>   ```

---

**More Info:**

> [Load environment configurations and properties with Spring
>   Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/load-environment-configurations-and-properties-with-spring-example/)

Answer (score 3):

try naming your property files like this:

```
application.properties
application-prod.properties
application-test.properties
```

and use "-Dspring.profiles.active=test" when starting your app

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment

Comment: I can use only 2 properties file : one for local and other for rest of the profiles

Comment: So use `application-local.properties` and `application.properties`